# What do you call this "asymmetric polarization"?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

I am considering this unusual polarization of EM waves:
[image]

which travels in the x-direction and has magnetic and electric fields as shown.
This can be produced by non-oscillatory currents.

What name is given to this type of polarization?

Comment: Isn't this just a plane wave propagating in the $\hat{x}$ direction?

Comment: I corrected the image, the axis of propagation is x, but you can call it anything.

Comment: @JohnRennie As far as I know, a linearly polarized plane wave has its electric field vector oscillating in a positive-negative fashion. This only has negative fields.

Comment: Ah, I see. I doubt any solution to Maxwell's equations has this form.

Comment: @JohnRennie Could you say why? I have solutions that look like those in the image. Note that the wave does not have to be sinusoidal (which avoids non-analytic fields at the null points).

Comment: Could you actually write down the field strengths $E(x,t)$ and $B(x,t)$? That'd be better to assess than a crude image

Comment: @ACuriousMind That would be a lot to type out. You can generate this wave by assuming that the vector potential $A_y$ at the boundary increases like a series of increasing steps in time. That is: constant then rising smoothly to a new constant value, then smoothly rising again to the next constant value, etc. I generate this by using a series of hyperbolic tangents with regular spacing and increasing strength. If you know the vector potential at the boundary, you can find the current profile needed to generate it. Using that as a boundary condition, you solve in Lorenz gauge. Hope that helps.